# " too logical" in UX Design

Tags: interview, logic

This is a very strange question that I'm about to ask that I'm not sure if anyone else has ever received.

I've been doing UX Design now for roughly 5 years, and I thoroughly enjoy it. I'm heavier on the flow side of things than I am wire frames, but still of course include wire frames in my process.

Today I was in an interview and I was told by the manager interviewing me, that I was indeed "too logical". I must admit that I did go pretty deep with the process flow and the thought behind the design within 15 minutes, but I was obviously wrong for doing this and they had mentioned that I should have only done one or two wire frames with a shorter process flow.

To add to this, I also misinterpreted what was said and definitely should have asked more questions before proceeding into the design process, that's my fault. But the words "too logical" are still playing over and over in my head.

Is it really possible to be "too logical" in UX Design? Is bridging the gap between designer and developer not the sole purpose of an UX Designer position in order to make the product better? Am I missing something?

I'm trying to find a take away from this, but all I've received has been "listen better" and "less is more".

Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds more like he meant you were over-thinking things and trying to get it right first time, whereas he'd prefer quick iterations. The latter would test or uncover any assumptions implicit in the "over-thinking" approach.

Comment: That makes sense too. Although I feel that sometimes putting some extra thought into things will save you a lot of time in the end. I suppose that too could be a problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It is possible to be too logical in UX design; i.e., to over-analyze a problem. That's one reason why developers tend to be bad at it.  Simpler is almost always better.

UX design is more than bridging the gap between designers and developers.  From my point of view, UX design is about making things easy and understandable for the user; i.e., UX designers should know about human factors engineering as it applies to software.

I think the advice you were given was good.  But I wouldn't dwell on it too long, lest you shake your self-confidence the next time you're interviewed.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to hear. Although, now I seem to have a much bigger problem on my plate. I am very analytical, and at times too logical. Should I be seeking out development over design?

Comment: I've long believed you should "do what you love".  If you enjoy UX Design, I'd stick with it.  Just because you tend to over-analyze doesn't mean it will always be that way.  I was like that once, but am no longer (I think).  But I'd suggest finding a good book or two on UX Design and reading them.  Remember that making the simple appear complex is much easier to do than making the complex appear simple.  Use those analytical skills of yours to constantly question if there's an easier way for your users.  Just don't over do it!

Comment: I appreciate that advice E L. I really do enjoy UX Design and only want to learn more and get better at it. I honestly think this was the first big step towards a better career in this field. I think ultimately I will strive to be better, but also be more active here on UX Exchange, there is a lot of great advice and good discussions here.

Comment: Sorry, but _"That's one reason why developers tend to be bad at it"_ is nonsense. I can easily flip it and say "designers are too creative and want to re-invent the wheel every time, that's one reason why they tend to be bad at it"

Comment: @L.Mller I've actually had that told to me, which is another reason why I pursued more of a design oriented career. Both of these examples happen a lot in interviews, well, the ones I've experienced.